# wordpress loop and tax_query - filtering posts depending on selected dropdowns

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have stucked with one thing in terms of cpt filtering. I'm working on an ajax filtering function using two dropdowns. I am passing arguments in the following way:

```
$args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
        'order' => $_POST['date'], // ASC or DESC
    'post_type' => 'career',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
 
    // for taxonomies / categories
    if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) &&  isset( $_POST['taxonomyfilter'] ))
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'job-category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'job-country',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['taxonomyfilter']
            )
        );
```

And the loop works if I select the value in the both taxonomies/dropdowns. The issue starts when I select the value only in the one dropdown and then submit it. Because then it somehow ignores the value selected and still shows some posts but rather in a random way.

I have a suspection it might be related to relation. But again changing it to OR doesn't work. So what Im trying to achieve is to make a kind of logic that IF only one of the dropdowns is selected (and the second has no value) then show posts matching only that one criteria.

Comment: Why are you adding tax queries for _both_, when there was a value passed only for _one_?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. When the page loads then all the posts are being loaded. On top of them I have two dropdowns and submit button. When a user selects value only from one dropdown, then it should discard selection from the 2nd dropdown. When he selects values in both dropdowns, then should show precise lists of posts meeting both criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your tax_query and add additional filters in tax_query only if relative field has a value.

```
$args['tax_query'] = [
    'relation' => 'AND',
];

foreach([
    'job-category' => 'categoryfilter',
    'jov-country' => 'taxonomyfilter',
] as $taxonomy => $field_name) {
    // Used an error control operator to get value from post
    // also sanitaze user input
    $field_value = sanitize_text_field(@$_POST[$field_name]);

    // Guard block if value is empty
    if(!$field_value) {
        continue;
    }

    // Add specific condition
    $args['tax_query'][] = [
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $field_value,
    ];
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks - it doesn't work when both dropdowns has value selected

Comment: Oh, i get it, my bad. In that case, can you dump an actual SQL query that is generated by WPQuery?